# orderby property of query on pre_get_posts returns incorrect value

Tags: php, theme-development, columns

I am attempting to implement some custom sorting logic for a column but are facing issues in the pre_get_posts hook. The value of the orderby property on the query is not returning the value corresponding to the currently selected sorted column. I have no plugins installed and are using the latest wordpress version 6.1.1 for context. Here is my code:

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'users_custom_column_query' );

function users_custom_column_query( $query ) {
    write_log( 'is main query: ' . var_export( $query->is_main_query(), true ) );
    write_log( 'orderby value: ' . var_export( $query->get( 'orderby' ), true ) );
}
```

Which outputs this on my local test site:

```php
// Output on page site.local/wp-admin/users.php?orderby=email&order=asc:
// is main query: true
// orderby value: ''
```

Expected output is 'email'. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `pre_get_posts` is for posts and `WP_Query`, but `users.php` lists users not posts. Lots of plugins/themes etc use queries too, `pre_get_posts` can be called multiple times on a request. Are you sure you didn't want `pre_get_users`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tom J Nowell pointed out in the comments, I was targeting the wrong hook for this. Correct hook to modify the WP_User_Query is pre_get_users.